# Proving small tails of sum of $|c_k|$ given small tails of sum of $|k^2 c_k|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Given that, for any $\epsilon$, we can choose $N$ such that:

$$\sum_{k>N} |k^2 c_k|^2 < \epsilon$$

How can I prove that, for any $\epsilon' > 0$, we can find an $N$ such that:

$$\sum\limits_{k > N} |c_k| < \epsilon'$$

Comment: You should explain what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $\varepsilon = 1$, we see that there is $N_0$ such that for all $k>N_0$ we have $|k^2c_k|^2<1$, which means that $|c_k|<\frac{1}{k^2}$ for all $k>N_0$. Hence, the tail of the sequence $\{|c_k|\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is upper-bounded by the convergent series $1/k^2$, which proves the claim.